# AsyncTask Error onPostExexcute is never called

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask, inputstream

This is my AsyncTask

```
private class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sqNameTV.setText("");
        sqdescriptionTV.setText("");
        sqdetailedDescriptionTV.setText("");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {





        try {
            URL url = new URL(URLi);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append(" ");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                String ress = stringBuilder.toString();
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(ress);
                JSONArray itemListElement = object.getJSONArray("itemListElement");
                InputStream is;
                for (int i = 0; i < itemListElement.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = itemListElement.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject results = c.getJSONObject("result");
                    JSONObject image = results.getJSONObject("image");
                    String contentUrl = image.getString("contentUrl");
                    is = (InputStream) new URL(contentUrl).getContent();
                    d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                }
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response, Drawable dd) {
        if (response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "post execute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("INFO", response);

        // Appropriate error handling code
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray itemListElement = object.getJSONArray("itemListElement");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemListElement.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = itemListElement.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject results = c.getJSONObject("result");
                String name = results.getString("name").toString();
                String description = results.getString("description").toString();
                JSONObject image = results.getJSONObject("image");
                String contentUrl = image.getString("contentUrl");
                JSONObject detailedDescription = results.getJSONObject("detailedDescription");
                String articleBody = detailedDescription.getString("articleBody");
                sqNameTV.setText(name);
                sqdescriptionTV.setText(description);
                Drawable imageQ = LoadImageFromWebOperations(contentUrl);
                Log.e("TAG",contentUrl);
                sIV.setImageDrawable(d);
                sqdetailedDescriptionTV.setText(articleBody);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            sqNameTV.setText("Empty");
            sqdescriptionTV.setText("No Data Found");
            sqdetailedDescriptionTV.setText("Could not find any data on " + queryyy);
        }
    }
}
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String strPhotoUrl) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(strPhotoUrl).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        Log.e("TAGG", strPhotoUrl);
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAGG", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
```

And it WAS functioning properly. Then later on since I needed to get an image as well, I put some JSON parsing in doInBackground(). Then for some reason onPostExecute is never called. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Have you test is you have a timeout or an exception?

Comment: No. My progress bar just keeps on spinning. No log that onPostExecute started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter in the AsyncTask declaration defines the return type of the AsyncTask.

```
private class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
```

So, according to your definition, the `onPostExecute()` method should be just expecting a `String` as a parameter, because you are returning only a String from the background thread. Your definition of `onPostExecute()` has two parameters. Should be just one, the one defined as the return type of the AsyncTask.

Comment: Hi again swayam! But am i not just returning `return stringBuilder.toString();`?

Comment: Hi, again! Yes, return statement is fine. The problem lies with `protected void onPostExecute(String response, Drawable dd)`.

Comment: Thanks. I am such a big..... I can't believe I made such a silly mistake. Thanks so much once again!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! Don't forget to accept the answer to help future readers as well! :)

Comment: May the Droid be with you! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `onPostExecute()` behaves as an independent method -

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response, Drawable dd)
```

According to the design of the AysncTask, if you want the Android system to invoke `onPostExecute()` , then it should be designed this way -

```
protected void onPostExecute(String response)
```

For

```
 AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>, 
1st Void - Paramater type in doInBackground()
2nd Void - Paramater type in onProgressUpdate()
3rd String - Return type of  doInBackground() and Paramater type in onPostExecute()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had to give it to the 1st answer though. Sorry. +1